# Joining 2 mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

table skills

```
id | skill
----------
1 | skill 1
2 | skill 2
3 | skill 3
```

second table user_skills, where user_skills.skill_1 = skills.id (1) AND user_skills.skill_2 = skills.id (2) AND user_skills.skill_3 = skills.id (3)

```
id | user_id | skill_1 | skill_2 | skill_3
------------------------------------------
1  | 3       | 2       | 4       | 5
```

I need output like this:

```
skill 1 -- 2
skill 2 -- 4
skill 3 -- 5
```

I tried left join, but no result. Any help is welcome.

Omeri

Comment: Hi, prepare a test case using http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Sorry but could you please restructure the question, because it's really unclear.

Comment: Your table structure seems to be wonky. Looking at your table structure, it's the question of the database design. Your database design is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Hi You should not store groups of values as columns, or group of values in a column, in a table. This violates the First Normal Form of the database design, and will come back and bite you in the wrong place.

Your User Skill Table should be like this:

```
id | user_id | skill
------------------------------------------
1  | 3       | 2
2  | 3       | 4
3  | 3       | 5
```

Comment: Having said that, I did not understand your question. Could you add the Column Names for your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

in first table(skills) i have onli skill names with id-s. in second table i have user skill levels. skill_1 is equal with skill id 1 from skills table. so i need that output all skills and user skill levels

skillname(from first table) - skill level (from second table)

omeri.